# No autocomplete for Tailwind CSS in PhpStorm using Laravel Sail

Tags: phpstorm, tailwind-css, laravel-sail

I've followed these steps: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/tailwind-css.html.

I'm using Laravel Sail and Vite. And PhpStorm 2022.3.2 (Build #PS-223.8617.59, built on January 30, 2023)

My "Node interpreter" is set to `docker://sail-8.2/app:latest/node`.
Package manager is set to `npm`.

I can use custom Tailwind classes, which Vite will happily build instantly with `sail npm run dev` running in the background.

I just cannot get autocomplete in PhpStorm. Only for classes that I've actually used somewhere else in the page/project.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sadly the remote node.js (docker) / tailwind does not seem to be currently supported as per these tickets: 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53172/CSS-class-auto-completion-for-Tailwind-does-not-work-when-using-a-remote-Node.js-interpreter-Docker-ssh 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-48671/Tailwind-CSS-Autocompletion-not-Working-with-remote-Node-interpreter

Comment: @LazyOne Ah, good find. I'm actually not sure how this is supposed to work (if it did, that is). How is the CSS plugin getting all possible Tailwind classes? Could I "fix" this by running node on my host too? Or maybe only on my host?

Comment: Yes, try local node interpreter -- as far as I see it should work OK (not using Tailwind myself so cannot test it for you, but it is officially supported; it's just the "remote/docker" that is not currently supported)

Comment: Same scenario, but not working at all with the local node interpreter... @John, did you make it work? In that case, how? Thanks.

Comment: @andcl I'm only using node on my Mac host now. It works for Tailwind autocomplete.

Comment: @John It doesn't work in my case most probably because of OS... I am using Windows 10 host. Thanks anyway! I will keep searching and waiting :(

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you cant use docker node with the tailwind plugin in phpstorm yet.

I use Windows with WSL2 and when I configured `nvm`, run `npm install` on the WSL and added this node interpreter to `PHPSTORM` , it worked for me.